# C# Json DeserializeObject Array

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a little login thing, and I keep getting stuck. I have been working on this for the whole day. I only want to make it so when the key is put in a textbox, it will check the key and return the username. I have made a JSON File for it.

```
public static string getUser(string key)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient { Proxy = null };
        string link = client.DownloadString("https://snyicalistic123.000webhostapp.com/aqua.json");
        dynamic jsa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<userGroup>(link);
        string username = jsa.user1[link.IndexOf(key)].username;
        return username;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return $"Failed... {e.Message}";
    }
}

public class user
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public bool isBanned { get; set; }
}

public class userGroup
{
    public user user1;
}
```

Comment: I guess the object was not properly deserialized. Could you please provide a sample of the json which you get from downloading?

Comment: your json is in a wrong format

Comment: its JSON I wrote. could you give me an example of JSON please?

Comment: @JackGreen I was asking about the json for understanding the structure it has. But then noticed that I can see that json by opening this on the browser: https://snyicalistic123.000webhostapp.com/aqua.json :)
So now there is no need of providing it.
Please check the answer below which is based on the json structure you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is in a wrong format

you should have a json like THIS

```
[
{
    "username": "Preazy_RBLX",
    "isBanned": false
}, {
    "username": "inazmul123",
    "isBanned": false
}, {
    "username": "Slormracer7",
    "isBanned": false
}
]
```

Then you should be able to DeserializeObject to something like this

```
dynamic jsa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(link);
```

Comment: The json is an object that contains objects. Whereas you're looking for a list of objects. As João Paulo Amorim shows, change the outer brackets to [ ] and it'll fix your problem

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Aqueous.userGroup>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments I am now recieving this error

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Aqueous.Objects.user>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the structure of the json you have.

But if it's not under your control you can deserialize it as a
dictionary of `string-user` pairs to solve the problem:

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient { Proxy = null };
    string link = client.DownloadString("https://snyicalistic123.000webhostapp.com/aqua.json");
    Dictionary<string, user> jsa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, user>>(link);
    string username = jsa[key].username;
    return username;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K2sfxe) is a dotnet fiddle to test the code.